# IIS redirect to another site via sub-directory?

Tags: iis

I think I know my answer but wanted to verify it with the community.

I have an IIS 6 server (Win 2K3) and a new sub-directory/site coming up -- www.example.com/newsite

On a IIS7.5/W2K8 server I have newsite setup there as a website.

Would I need to use the ISAPI_Rewrite module to send users that click to www.example.com/newsite to the IP address/newsite on the other server? I don't have a domain name for that other site because we don't want users going to that directory on it's own (they use the example.com site to login and then it passes an auth token to the other site).

Just trying to figure out the best way to tackle this.

~Allen

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory in IIS and in the app/directory properties redirect that location to the server you want.